# Implicit conversion declared in companion object is not called

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit-declaration

I am trying sample programs on Scala **implicits**. I am trying to implement one solution from the "**Scala for the Impatient**" book.

I have written as Fraction class having two member variables **numerator** and **denominator** with an operation overloading method "***(fraction)**", so that we can call multiplication on Fraction objects like **fration1 * fraction2 * fraction3**.

Now, I tried to implement **intToFraction** and **fractionToInt** implicit methods, so that we can also write syntax like 2*fraction1*3. I tried implementing those methods in companion object of Fraction class. But those methods are not getting  called.

As suggested by Scala docs, Scala compiler will try to find out implicit implementation in the companion object. Here, we are performing operation on objects of Fraction class, so I assume, implicits declared in Fraction should have been called automatically. I also tried by importing implicit methods explicitly but it did not work.

Please find code snippet below for your reference.

```
package com.example.implicits.conversion

object ImplicitConversionTester extends  App {
  val f1 = Fraction(4,2)
  val result = 2 * f1
  println(s"${f1 * f1}")
  println(s"${result}")
 
}

class Fraction(val numerator : Int,val denominator : Int) {

  def *(fraction : Fraction): Fraction = {
    println("##### Call to operator overloading *")
    Fraction(this.numerator*fraction.numerator, this.denominator*fraction.denominator)
  }

  override def toString: String = s"Fraction($numerator,$denominator) ===== ${numerator/denominator}"

}

object Fraction {
  def apply(numerator: Int, denominator: Int): Fraction = new Fraction(numerator, denominator)

  implicit def intToFraction(num : Int) = {
    println("##### intToFraction")
    Fraction(num,1)
  }

  implicit def fractionToInt(fr : Fraction) = {
    println("##### fractionToInt")
    fr.numerator/fr.denominator
  }

}
```

any suggestion to fix this problem appreciated!

Comment: While the companion object is part of the implicit scope for implicit values, I am not sure if it is for implicit conversions. - Anyways, this kind of conversions are discouraged, it is recommended to instead have a couple of extension methods like `toFraction` & `toInt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the declaration of the implicit methods without explicitly mentioned return types. I did not mention the return type in the code snippet above. Implicits are working fine after adding the function return type. So, There is no need to explicitly import the implicit functions in **ImplicitConversionTester** class to fix the problem.

Below is the updated fraction class to fix the error:

```
class Fraction(val numerator : Int,val denominator : Int) {

  val test = 2

  def *(fraction : Fraction): Fraction = {
    println("##### Call to operator overloading *")
    Fraction(this.numerator*fraction.numerator, this.denominator*fraction.denominator)
  }

  override def toString: String = s"Fraction($numerator,$denominator) ===== ${numerator/denominator}"
}

object Fraction {
  def apply(numerator: Int, denominator: Int): Fraction = new Fraction(numerator, denominator)

  implicit def intToFraction(num : Int) : Fraction = { // RETURN TYPE FRACTION
    println("##### intToFraction")
    Fraction(num,1)
  }
  implicit def fractionToInt(fr : Fraction) : Int  = { // ADDED RETURN TYPE INT
    println("##### fractionToInt")
    fr.numerator/fr.denominator
  }

}
```

Sharing below more details about how Scala compiler looksup the implicit conversion. Below image is taken from the book "**Scala for the Impatient**".

[image]

As mentioned in the book, Scala compiler gives first preference to companion object of the **source** or the **target** type.

Here, What is **source** and **target** type that depends on the order of expression. For example, if the expression is "**2*Fraction(2,4)**", the expression is evaluated from left to right. Int "**2**" has already implementation present for multiplication method **(*)**. So, compiler tries to find implicit conversion from "Fraction to Int" in "Int" type first. As "Int" type does not have any implementation for "Fraction to Int", compiler will lookup companion object of Fraction class where it finds a method "**fractionToInt**". In this example, target type is Int and Source type is Fraction.

Consider the example of expression **"Fraction(2,4)*2"**, Here as the Fraction class has implementation available for multiplication "*", compiler tries to find implicit for converting Int to Fraction. So target type is Fraction and  Source type is Int. As there is no such implicit method/class present in **Int** class, compiler looksup Fraction companion object and finds "**IntToFraction**" implicit.

Comment: Could you find the reason why the result type is mandatory for an implicit function to work?

Answer (score 4):

You are right that the scala compiler looks for the implicit first in

- current scope then
- in companion scope then
- in imported scope

And in your case compiler looking for the implicit in the scope of the main singleton object `ImplicitConversionTester` and it will not find anything since there is no any implicit available. If you import the implicit then it should work -

```
object Implicit extends App {

import Fraction._

  class Fraction(val numerator : Int,val denominator : Int) {
    def * (fraction : Fraction): Fraction = {
      println("##### Call to operator overloading *")
      Fraction(this.numerator*fraction.numerator, this.denominator*fraction.denominator)
    }
  }
  object Fraction {
    def apply(numerator: Int, denominator: Int): Fraction = new Fraction(numerator, denominator)

    implicit def intToFraction(num : Int) = {
      println("##### intToFraction")
      Fraction(num,1)
    }

    implicit def fractionToInt(fr : Fraction) = {
      println("##### fractionToInt")
      fr.numerator/fr.denominator
    }
  }
  println(Fraction(1,2) * 2)
}
```

Comment: Importing "implicit class" or "implicit method" explicitly is one way. But, What I was expecting here is, we are trying to evaluate "2 * Fraction". Here,  Int type "2" has already method implementation available for multiplication "*", but Fraction is not eligible type for that method. So, compiler will try to find some conversions for Fraction class. First it will look up in local scope. As we have not imported any implicts explicitly, compiler will look up for implicits in Fraction companion object. Here, we have defined implicit "fractionToInt" in Fraction companion object.

Comment: Here, we have defined implicit "fractionToInt" in Fraction companion object. But, why scala compiler fails to look up the implicit "fractionToInt" ?

Comment: while evaluating the expression scala compiler will look for implicit if given method/function is not available with given object type. Since `Int` already has a multiplication method available with it and due to the operator associativity method with Int 2 is getting invoked. But if you change the order like `fraction1  *  2` then you will get the result with fraction result type.